# API method for sending attached files in conversations on Service Console

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

we are using Aura Components that interact with Conversations in Service Console, and we are using the `lightning:conversationToolkitAPI` to send messages. However, we couldn't find a way to attach and send files as part of those messages, which is a feature available in `Enhanced Conversation` UI component on Messaging In-App and Web feature in Salesforce.

Is there any API or anything we are missing here that would allow us to send files along with the text messages?

Thanks in advance!